# Using Sass compressed output while leaving theme comment header for Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, compass-sass, sass

How do other Wordpress theme developers incorporate Sass into their theme development while taking advantage of its compressed output style? Sass compressed removes ALL comments, so I currently have an empty style.css with my theme declaration and an @import calling the minified css from compass, but this hardly seems like the best solution.

Has anybody found a way around this? What would be the best solution if not?

http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development#Theme_Stylesheet

http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#id40

Comment: I tend to use the same method - Wordpress is picky about the theme declaration

Answer (score 42):

**SUPER SHORT VERSION:** Use `/*! loud comments */` and compile the SCSS just before packaging and distributing.

Two part answer, "old part" first:

I used Sass/SCSS when developing my "Orin" theme: https://github.com/founddrama/orin

**Part One:**

- In my `src/scss` directory, I keep all of my `_include.scss` files and the `style.scss` file that has all of the `@import` statements.
- During development, I just run the usual `sass --watch` (although it's an extra step to remember to save the `style.scss` file).
- Once your SCSS source is looking good and committed to version control, you can simply build the `style.scss` into `style.css` and check that into version control for the Theme that gets distributed.

In my case, "Orin" is just for me, so I perform the build when I update it on the blog server, but the SCSS compilation can just as easily be done prior to packaging/distribution. The build script I'm using is [here](https://github.com/founddrama/orin/blob/master/bin/deploy.sh) (in that Github repo); the gist of it being:

1. `touch` to create the `style.css` output file;
2. apply the license text;
3. compile the SCSS and append it to `style.css`.

**Part Two:**

More recent versions of Sass include support for `/*! loud comments */`; meaning that I need to get off my lazy butt and update to:

1. Include the license text and theme description right there in `style.scss` using the loud comments;
2. update the build/deploy script to simply compile the SCSS.

Comment: @NathanArthur - Presuming you're talking about the minifier built into Sass, **yes.** The point of the `/*! loud comment */` is that the minifier keeps it, but removes all the _other_ comments.

Answer (score 2):

Well, i would suggest you to use [Compass](http://compass-style.org/) . 
The comment should look like this:

```
/*! A loud SASS comment */
```