# Sass compressed output removing loud comment

Tags: sass, gruntjs

Okay, so I'm working on a Wordpress theme and I'm using Sass with Grunt. The problem is that although in my primary SCSS file I have a loud comment like this, the compressed output still doesn't include it.

```
/*!
Theme Name:         Theme Name
Theme URI:          http://theme.com
Description:        Theme Description.
Version:            1.0.0
Author:             Me
Author URI:         http://me.com
*/

/* Global config */
@import "config/variables"; // Your custom variables
@import "config/colors"; // Your custom color scheme
@import "config/settings"; // Default settings file. Uncomment each setting you need to change

/* Foundation 5 */
@import "foundation"; // Foundation 5 by Zurb

/* Site structure */
@import "site/structure"; // Your site structure
```

I've tried changing the outputStyle to nested in Gruntfile and the comments are showing this way but obviously I don't want to do that on the live site. Any idea what's causing this?

Edit: here's the theme I'm working with https://github.com/olefredrik/foundationpress/

Comment: Are you certain something else isn't stripping it?  Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4893215/using-sass-compressed-output-while-leaving-theme-comment-header-for-wordpress

Comment: I have no idea what's going on, where should I look if something else is stripping it? I read the question you've linked and a lot of other stuff before posting this, but I still don't know what the problem is. I am new to Sass and this is my first time working with Grunt though, so it might be some stupid little thing. Also, here's the theme I'm working on as base, in case it helps: https://github.com/olefredrik/foundationpress/

Comment: When you type `grunt sass` by itself what do the generated .css files look like?

Comment: I just tried that, getting exactly the same output. Compressed, absolutely no comments at all.

Comment: Have you tried compiling Sass outside of Grunt?

Comment: This is a current issue with the libsass compiler: https://github.com/hcatlin/libsass/issues/348

Answer (score 1):

With the `!`, your multi-line comments should be preserved regardless of the output style you're compiling to ([nested, expanded, compact or compressed](http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#output_style)). Thus something outside of Sass compilation must be stripping the comments - probably somewhere in the Grunt compilation.